# Update or Fresh Installation to Android Studio 3.5 not opening crashed at startup itself [OS : Windows10 Pro]

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated android studio to 3.5 [image: Current Version], when i opened android studio not opening get crashed at startup itself. 
If I delete .android and .AndroidStudio3.5 and .graddle folder in this path "C:\Users\xxxxx" then i can able to see [image: Home Page], even though i cant able to create new project or open existing project, on creating or opening existing project android studio get crashed. kindly solve my problem.

**Note : Fresh Installation also not working**

OS: Windows10 Pro

**Edited** : This is log message in this path **"‪C:\Users\xxxx\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\log\idea.log"**

```
   2019-08-23 09:49:48,526 [ain Thread]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,558 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, 09 Aug 2019 05:32) 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,558 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,558 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,558 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.202-b03 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,559 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -da -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio3.5 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\xxxx\java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\xxxx\java_error_in_studio.hprof 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,559 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge-64.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,559 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=Cp1252 file=Cp1252 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,635 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 76 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,641 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2019-08-23 09:49:48,739 [e-1483-b03]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - User scale factor: 1.0 
2019-08-23 09:49:49,716 [entQueue-0]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - CPU cores: 4; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@42ed1933[Running, parallelism = 3, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@763166e7 
2019-08-23 09:49:49,758 [entQueue-0]   INFO -     #com.intellij.util.ui.JBUI - System scale factor: 1.0 (JRE-managed HiDPI) 
2019-08-23 09:49:50,249 [ger Loader]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:50,250 [ger Loader]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:50,380 [entQueue-0]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - load plugin descriptors took 454 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:50,491 [entQueue-0]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 38 plugins initialized in 565 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:50,492 [entQueue-0]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android APK Support (1.0), Android Games (1.0), Android NDK Support (1.0), Android Support (10.3.5), App Links Assistant (0.1), Copyright (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Coverage (191.8026.42.35.5791312), EditorConfig (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Firebase App Indexing (0.1), Firebase Services (0.1), Firebase Testing (1.0), Git Integration (191.8026.42.35.5791312), GitHub (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Google Cloud Tools Core (0.2.8), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (0.2.8), Google Developers Samples (0.3.1), Google Login (1.0), Google Services (0.1), Gradle (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Groovy (191.8026.42.35.5791312), I18n for Java (191.8026.42.35.5791312), IDEA CORE (191.8026.42.35.5791312), IntelliJ Configuration Script (191.8026.42.35.5791312), IntelliLang (191.8026.42.35.5791312), JUnit (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Java Bytecode Decompiler (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Java Stream Debugger (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Kotlin (1.3.41-release-Studio3.5-1), Mercurial Integration (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Properties Support (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Settings Repository (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Smali Support (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Subversion (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Task Management (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Terminal (191.8026.42.35.5791312), Test Recorder (1.0), TestNG-J (191.8026.42.35.5791312), YAML (191.8026.42.35.5791312) 
2019-08-23 09:49:51,652 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1226 
2019-08-23 09:49:51,703 [le Watcher]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2019-08-23 09:49:51,750 [le Watcher]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2019-08-23 09:49:52,900 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2019-08-23 09:49:52,911 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for interface com.intellij.openapi.extensions.PluginDescriptor 
2019-08-23 09:49:52,951 [d thread 4]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2019-08-23 09:49:52,971 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release 
2019-08-23 09:49:53,145 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index exts enumerated:120, number of extensions:43 
2019-08-23 09:49:53,157 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Index scheduled:11 
2019-08-23 09:49:53,183 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - All stub exts enumerated:20, number of extensions:50 
2019-08-23 09:49:53,184 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - tellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl - stub exts update scheduled:0 
2019-08-23 09:49:53,553 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 19 project components initialized in 269 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:53,985 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=12, fontScale=1.0 
2019-08-23 09:49:54,034 [oader Pool]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 1262 ms spent to cache options in application 
2019-08-23 09:49:54,035 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider$Activity took 1262 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:54,906 [cture Pool]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:1745 
2019-08-23 09:49:55,262 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - 88 application components initialized in 5339ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:55,282 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 8490 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:55,680 [cture Pool]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:774 
2019-08-23 09:49:55,939 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - OS doesn't support touchbar, skip nst loading 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,286 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 328 ms spent on EDT to cache options in application 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,288 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Found Studio home directory at: 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio' 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,288 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at 'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/sdk' 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,288 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at 'C:/Program Files/Android/sdk' 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,288 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation. 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,289 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Examined and not found a valid Android SDK path: ANDROID_HOME environment variable 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,289 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Examined and not found a valid Android SDK path: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,289 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Examined and not found a valid Android SDK path: Last SDK used by Android tools 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,303 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - rd.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider - Overriding welcome frame to be resizable 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,389 [d thread 2]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 23-08-2019 09:43 AM) 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,661 [d thread 2]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,744 [d thread 2]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File C:\Users\XXXX\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,752 [3-thread-2]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,759 [3-thread-1]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,764 [-thread-12]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,764 [3-thread-9]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,786 [3-thread-8]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,786 [3-thread-3]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,786 [-thread-11]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/sdk-updates/offline-repo/offline-repo.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,786 [-thread-10]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,786 [3-thread-7]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,791 [3-thread-6]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,788 [3-thread-5]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:56,788 [3-thread-4]   INFO - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-cn/sys-img2-1.xml 
2019-08-23 09:49:57,396 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader took 3353 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:57,487 [oader Pool]   INFO - dk.ClangTidyInspectionProvider - Clang-tidy inspection is enabled.} 
2019-08-23 09:49:58,838 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader took 1441 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:59,275 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader took 436 ms 
2019-08-23 09:49:59,279 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoClassPresentationUpdater took 4 ms 
2019-08-23 09:50:00,424 [d thread 3]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 166 project components initialized in 844 ms 
2019-08-23 09:50:01,443 [d thread 3]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 2 module(s) loaded in 1016 ms 
2019-08-23 09:50:01,695 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - artup.AndroidStudioInitializer - Failed to disable 'org.intellij.plugins.intelliLang.inject.groovy.GrConcatenationInjector' 
2019-08-23 09:50:01,829 [d thread 4]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found
```

I have sdk at this path "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"

Comment: try uninstalling, then clearing all the cache and local folders

Comment: @ManojPerumarath If i uninstalled android studio the folder in the path "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android" is also get removed? In that folder i have data around 80gb i dont want lose that. Is it possible to uninstall android studio without losing that folder?

Comment: copy the data to somewhere else

Comment: @ManojPerumarath i dont know what is the use of update then...if i do fresh installation on each update. anyway thanks

Comment: Anyone working in android studio 3.5 version???

Comment: Just upgraded to version 3.5. Didn't face any issue yet.

Comment: @salmanwahed sir, Did you try by close and open the android studio

Comment: Yes. Closed and reopened. Seems fine. I am on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Sir, I am using windows10 lenovo model with 8gb ram and 64bit processor

Comment: I was also facing this issue, and this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668860/my-android-studio-keeps-crashing-after-updating-it-from-3-4-to-3-5 solved it for me.

Comment: Just upgrade to 3.5 for 2 days (actually, it's more like fresh install because 3.5 told me to uninstall previous version before start install 3.5), works fine. I'm also using Windows10 x64, the different I see was your JRE(JetBrains s.r.o), I'm using Oracle's JDK 1.8.    Hope it would help...

Comment: sir I skipped this version and downgraded android studio to 3.4 itself.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I don't have high enough reputation to comment, but I can answer.  I'm also experiencing the same problem.  Android Studio starts to open and then crashes as it tries to open a project.  I don't really see any errors in the idea.log, at least nothing is labeled as an error, but I do see and INFO message with: Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation.
I have tried upgrading an exiting install.  Uninstalling and deleting folders and installing 3.5 fresh, but nothing works.  I can uninstall 3.5 and reinstall 3.4 so I'm not completely dead in the water, but it seems odd that we would be the only 2 people with this problem.  Of note I also have a lenovo running Win 10, but I'd be surprised if that was the issue.

Update: 8/23/19 10:23am
AH HA!!!  I've fixed it.  I deleted my C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android folder.  Then I reopened Android Studio (to the main opening page, not so that it was opening a project and crashing.  I had to delete the C:\Users\xxx.AndroidStudio3.5 folder so that it would start at the beginning again).  After reopening Andriod Studio I was prompted that I didn't have an Android sdk.  I reinstalled that to C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and now I can open Android Studio.

Update: 9/2/19
No longer working.  3.5 is unusable.

Comment: Yes, I tried but no solution worked, now I downgraded android studio.

Comment: I delete `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android` folder, `C:\Users\XXX\.android` folder and `C:\Users\XXX\.AndroidStudio3.5` folder and it works

Comment: This actually stopped working and I'm going to have to install 3.4 as well again now too.  What a complete failure of an upgrade system...  :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was to do with the SDK path being changed or deleted during the upgrade for some reason.

The log file at C:\Users\MyProfile.AndroidStudio3.5\system\log was reporting that the Android SDK location was not found.

After updating the ANDROID_HOME path to where my sdk resides, it seemed to open my project again, however after a system restart, the issue persisted.

I reopened Android studio, but cancelled the project load , went into the SDK Manager, set a new location and downloaded the Android SDK from scratch. Seems to be working OK.

If that doesn't work, the log file should at least show you something useful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: see my edited question, i placed log file too.. i am not able to understand that file...

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the Android SDK, see lines:

Looking for Android SDK at 'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/sdk' 
Looking for Android SDK at 'C:/Program Files/Android/sdk' 
Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation. 
Examined and not found a valid Android SDK path: ANDROID_HOME environment variable 
Examined and not found a valid Android SDK path: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable 
Examined and not found a valid Android SDK path: Last SDK used by Android tools 

Try putting your Android sdk in C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/ and restart